# direct stdout to cache

Tags: terminal

Does anyone happen to know how to direct STDOUT in Terminal to Cache? Sometimes I would like to copy text from STDOUT somewhere else, e.g. my mail program, and it seems always a bit inconvenient to me to either copy the output manually or create a new temporary file.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Alex

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you're asking.  But if you're talking about capturing stdout to file whilst still being able to see it on the console, then you can use `tee` (assuming you're using *nix):

```
./myApp | tee stdout.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I think I was aiming at something else. E.g., I use `detex` to produce ASCII output from a tex-file which I want to send via email.

By chance, I have stumbled across the command I was looking for: `pbcopy`.

Now I use:

`detex file.tex | pbcopy`

... then I can paste the text into my mail program. The complementary command is `pbpaste'.

Thanks again for your quick answer!